# Will a US visa refusal affect an Irish visa application?

Tags: ireland

I am applying Irish for an business visa, but 3 months ago my US visa was refused. Is that going to affect my Irish visa application? Should I mention about my US visa refusal in the Irish visa application?

Answer (score 4):

If the online visa application form asks if you have been refused a visa before, you should answer honestly. If you withold the information when it's asked for, and the Irish authorities find out, they will probably refuse you on grounds of deception, and could possibly ban you for a long period.

The refusal will be taken into account by the Irish, but what effect it has will depend on the grounds for refusal and how that relates to your application with them. From the information you've given there's nothing more we can add.

If the online application doesn't ask for information about a refusal then there's no need to mention it. In this case it shouldn't affect your application.

Answer (score 2):

[The Irish Naturalisation and Immigration Service website](http://www.inis.gov.ie/), for atypical working scheme visas, clearly states the following:

6. Supporting documentation - Previous Visa Refusals

   > If you have been refused a visa in the past for any country, you must
   >   provide the details.
   >
   > The original letter issued to you by the authorities of that country
   >   must be provided with your application.
   >
   > **Not disclosing any previous visa refusals will result in your application being refused.**

Earlier today, when the [the Irish Naturalisation and Immigration Service website](http://www.inis.gov.ie/) was down, I was able to reference [the Embassy of Ireland, Great Britain's website](https://www.dfa.ie/media/embassylondon/ourservices/Business_visa_checklist_Jan_2018.pdf), and it also states that you are required to disclose any previous visa refusals and..."failure to disclose previous visa refusals will result in your Irish visa application being refused".

> 5. Previous Visa Refusal Details:
>
>    - Details of any previous Irish visa applications you have made, including any which were refused
>    - Details of any visa refusal(s) for any other country. Failure to disclose previous visa refusals will result in your Irish visa
>        application being refused
>    - Photocopy of any original documentation to do with previous visa refusal(s)